# Dynamic scheduled query based on timestamp

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to set up a scheduled query to run on the 1st of each month, and capture one month of data. However it should not be the previous month, but 2 months previous - due to delays in data being loaded in to the source table. The source table is partitioned by day on session_timestamp so refining this as much as possible will be of benefit to reducing query cost.

So far I have this:

```
WHERE
EXTRACT(YEAR
  FROM
    session_timestamp) = EXTRACT(YEAR
  FROM
    DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 2 MONTH))
  AND EXTRACT(MONTH
  FROM
    session_timestamp) = EXTRACT(MONTH
  FROM
    DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 2 MONTH))
```

This seems a highly inelegant solution but was intended to address cases where a year boundary would be crossed. However I can see from the "This script will process * when run." area that this is going to query everything in 2020 and not just in May 2020.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have pointed out, your query doesn't engage partition filter down to the 2 months of data which you want to query.

You don't have to do the year trick because DATE_TRUNC(..., MONTH) has year in it. Please try filter below:

```sql
-- Last day of the month
DATE(session_timestamp) <= DATE_SUB(DATE_TRUNC(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH), MONTH), INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
AND 
-- First day of the month
DATE(session_timestamp) >= DATE_TRUNC(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH), MONTH)
```